# $ sed -i does not change the file in place

Tags: bash, sed, text-files

I want remove the first two characters from a text file using sed utility. I want to do that (in place).

I try the followings but, it does not work:

```
$ sed -i 's/.{2}//' C:/Users/User/Desktop/text1.txt
$ sed -i -e 's/.{2}//' C:/Users/User/Desktop/text1.txt
$ sed -i'' 's/.{2}//' C:/Users/User/Desktop/text1.txt
```

It only works if I want a backup:

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/.{2}//' C:/Users/User/Desktop/text1.txt
```

or replace it in another file:

```
$ sed -r 's/.{2}//' C:/Users/User/Desktop/text1.txt > C:/Users/User/Desktop/text2.txt
```

if I type:

```
$ sed -i''
```

I got:

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
                 edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

What should be in [SUFFIX]?

**Note:**
**I want the replacement to be done on the original file and I do not like to have a backup file.**
Thanks

Comment: If you specify suffix, it will make a backup of your file before editing it in place, and suffix the backup's filename with the string you supplied.

Comment: makes backup if SUFFIX supplied. That's the answer to What should be in suffix? - If you supply a suffix, `sed -i'SUFFIX'` will create a backup file with a `'SUFFIX'`

Comment: Depending on the sed implementation `-i''` might be destructive, if it creates a "backup" file without a suffix and writes the changes to the same file.

Comment: If you use `-i.bak` (note that the backup suffix must be attached to the `-i` option with GNU `sed`; BSD `sed` has different rules), then given a file `text1.txt`, it will create a file `text1.txt.bak` as a backup.

Comment: @anubhava I try it. It doesn't change the original file, it change the backup file. I do not want to have a backup.

Comment: @nickb Yes. It change the backup! I want to change the original file and I do not like to have a backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not the in place but lacking `-r` option.  If you type

```
sed -i -r 's/.{2}//' ...
```

should work without backup.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. I spent two days around this problem.